# Meteor OnRendered function after child Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

Parent template `onRendered` function invokes before child template. How to execute parent templates function after child template rendered.

```
<template name="parent">
 {{#each object}}
  {{> child}}
 {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="child">
 <img src="someurl" data-src="someurl">
</template>
```

Now I need to execute some document ready function so

```
Template.parent.onRendered(function() { // doesnt invokes after child template
 $("img").unveil();
 $(window).trigger("lookup");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) and [afterFlush](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush) is probably what you need. Give something like this a try:

```
Template.parent.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    // replace the find with whatever is in your helper
    // which returns the children array/cursor
    if (Children.find().count()) {
      // this should run after the child templates have been rerendered
      Tracker.afterFlush(function() {
        $('img').unveil();
        $(window).trigger('lookup');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `Tracker.afterFlush` is an option that produces the needed behavior, the best way to do something like this is to just make use of the child template's `onRendered` function.  As soon as the child template is rendered then needed code will execute.

```
Template.child.onRendered(function() {
  this.$('img').unveil();
  this.$(window).trigger('lookup');
});
```

This approach is more natural and allows the child template to be used in any other template as well without "breaking"